# Hibernate: MappingException when execute getHibernateTemplate().update query

Tags: hibernate, exception, mapping

Got exception cause:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: UserDetails set confirmed=true where username=? and confirmationCode=?
```

when this code executed:

```
public void confirmUser(String username,String confirmationCode){
    getHibernateTemplate().update("UserDetails set confirmed=true where username=? and confirmationCode=?",new Object[]{username,confirmationCode});
}
```

**EDIT**

```
This query works OK:
    public String getUserMail(String username) {
        return (String) DataAccessUtils.uniqueResult(getHibernateTemplate().find(
                "select mail from UserDetails where username=?", new Object[] { username }));
    }
```

It means,that my `hbm.xml` should be OK too:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.UserDetails" table="users">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username"/>
        <property name="password" column="password"/>
        <property name="enabled" column="enabled"/>
        <property name="mail" column="mail"/>
        <property name="city" column="city"/>
        <property name="confirmed" column="confirmed"/>
        <property name="confirmationCode" column="confirmation_code"/>

        <set name="authorities" cascade="all" inverse="true">
            <key column="id" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="model.Authority"/>
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The question is, how to execute `update` method with set of parameters,because `getHibernateTemplate().update` assumes to pass `Object` to the method,but not `SQL` query.

Comment: Try to use fully qualified class name. And add some more details.

Comment: @ slayer_b do you propose to prepend it with package declaration?

Comment: Yes. Post your entity, configuration, dao i mean whole class. Because it seems like an error is in configuration.

Comment: I've updated post.Actually other query is working OK,using `UserDetails` mapping(see EDIT section,please).

Comment: Perhaps,the problem is in `getHibernateTemplate().update` method.Can't find appropriate examples.It's used `session.saveOrUpdate` in majority examples.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute update via `Hibernate ORM`, i used such construction:

```
SessionFactory sf = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory();
Session s = sf.openSession();
Query q = s.createQuery("UserDetails set confirmed=true
 where username:username and confirmationCode=:confirmationCode");
q.setString("username", username);
q.setString("confirmationCode", confirmationCode);
q.executeUpdate();
```

It was done ,due to `getHibernateTemplate().update` doesn't allow named params.
There should be object passed.